# Got "too many positional arguments" error on mongorestore

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to restore a existing mongodb database data..when i restore that by command line i got  this line as error

`2017-06-10T12:27:55.474+0530    too many positional arguments
2017-06-10T12:27:55.476+0530    try 'mongorestore --help' for more information`

I used this line 
  `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin> mongorestore F:\mongo_db\db`

Anyone please help me to get rid from this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after some time. Alternatively, we don't want to point the mongodb folder as of my question `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin>` . 
Simply Used this command . It restores the existing database, else creates the database if it's not existing.here,

`mongorestore --host <database-host> -d <database-name> --port <database-port> foldername`

Don't forgot to start mongodb server before use this command. For your localhost

`database-host --> localhost 
 database-name --> Your db Name
 database-port --> 27017`

Answer (score 1):

This error may occur when your folder name have **space** or **hyphen**(-) nomenclature, Please check the database contain folder name that it should not have any space or hyphen(-) in its nomenclature before restoring the database.

Below are used and tested cmd command line query for mongodb database restore

> C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongorestore -d foldername  folderpath

**Foldername** - Name of the folder where your database dump exist.

**Folderpath** - A complete path(url) of your system where it database dump exist.